# How to change displayed content from json objects with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, json

Trying to click through GIFS from reddit. The scope counter updates but the images displayed don't update. What are we doing wrong? Please and thank you.

```
angular.module('tasty', []);
angular.module('tasty')
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = "Tasty"
    $scope.counter = 24;
    console.log($scope.counter);
    $scope.increment = function(counter){
        $scope.counter += 1;
         $scope.updateGif();
      }
    $scope.decrement = function(counter){
        if(counter<=0)
            {
                return;
            }
         $scope.counter -= 1;
         }

    $scope.updateGif = function(counter) {
             console.log($scope.counter);
      $http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/gifrecipes.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.gifData = response.data.data.children[$scope.counter].data.preview.images[0].variants.gif.source.url;
                console.log($scope.gifData);
    });
    }
    $http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/gifrecipes.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.gifData = response.data.data.children[$scope.counter].data.preview.images[0].variants.gif.source.url;
                console.log($scope.gifData);
    });
});
```

--------------------HTML CODE -----------------------------------

```
<div>
<h1 ng-click="increment(counter)">Increment</h1>
</div>
<div>
<img src="{{gifData}}">
</div>
<div>
<h1 ng-click="decrement(counter)">Decrement</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a snippet using your code and worked just fine, but it took some time to load the images.

Also, use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of src.